# jQuery - slideToggle with (this) in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i'm trying to do is to show/hide multiple `<tr>` on a `OnClick` event. It's easier to directly go to the code to explain.

This is the PHP while loop that generates the `<tr>`

```
echo "<table class='table table-striped' style='margin-top:70px; width: 60%;'>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Persona</th>
        <th>Luogo di nascita</th>
        <th>Data di Nascita</th>
        <th>Codice Fiscale</th>
        <th>Note</th>
      </tr>";
while ($row_anagrafiche=mysql_fetch_row($risultato_query_anagrafica)) {
  $query_prestazioni=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prestazioni WHERE IDpersona='$row_anagrafiche[0]'");
  echo "<tr>
          <th><div class='showdata'>+</div></th>
          <td>" . $row_anagrafiche[1] . " " . $row_anagrafiche[2] . "</td>
          <td>" . $row_anagrafiche[3] . "</td></tr>
          ";
  while ($row_prestazioni=mysql_fetch_row($query_prestazioni)) {
    echo "<tr class='data' style='display:none;'>
            <td>ID Prest.: " . $row_prestazioni[0] . "</td>
            <td>Inizio: " . $row_prestazioni[3] . "</td>
            <td>Fine: " . $row_prestazioni[4] . "</td>
            <td>Importo: " . $row_prestazioni[5] . "€</td>
            <td>pagata: "; if ($row_prestazioni[6]==0) {
              echo "<font color='red'>No</font>";
            }else{
              echo "<font color='green'>Si</font>";
            }
            echo "</td>
            <td> " . $row_prestazioni[7] . "</td>
          </tr>

          ";
  }
  echo "</div>";
 }
echo "</table>";
}
```

And this is the jQuery code in the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.showdata').click(function() {
  $('.data').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
</script>
```

Right now when i click on the + the event is triggered in every row and it shows the content everywhere instead of showing just the interested rows. To fix it I'd like to pass, like in js, the `this` argument but i'don't know how to do it.

Comment: could you supply a jsfiddle with just the outputted html and jquery? it sounds to me like you might want to try $(this).parents(".data").slideToggle("fast"); instead of  $('.data').slideToggle("fast");

Comment: @mmmoustache i tried with the code you suggested but it doesn't work. Here the link to a sample of the output [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc7qunkm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use jQuery's [**`.nextUntil()`**](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method:

```
$('.showdata').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(":not(.data)").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/acx4pfhm/)</kbd>

---

> (...) Given a selector expression that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.nextUntil()` method searches through the successors of these elements in the DOM tree, stopping when it reaches an element matched by the method's argument. (...)

So, in other words, **`.nextUntil(":not(.data)")`** gathers all the `<tr>` elements after the clicked <kbd>+</kbd> and stops before the `<tr>` without `.data` class (before next <kbd>+</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your JSFiddle I *think* I understand what you're trying to achieve. If you take a look at my updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc7qunkm/1/), you can see that some html elements have a `data-id` custom attribute. Instead of using the `$(this)` selector, you can use a [custom data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to separate the different data sets:

```
<div class='showdata' data-id="1">+</div>
```

In my example, when you click on the `.showdata` elements, it finds all the rows that match the same data attribute value, of which it then calls the `slideToggle()` method.

So now if you try to replicate your html to match my JSFiddle, that's hopefully what you're after. If this data needs to be dynamic, I would use the value from the `$row_anagrafiche[0]` field (or a simple counter) for the values in your `data-id` attributes.